# access array through array huge performance loss

Tags: java, arrays, performance

lets look at the following two java methods:

```
static void performance1() {
    int a=0; 
    int b=0;
    int[] arrayA = { 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] arrayB = { 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4 };
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            a = arrayA[2];
            b = arrayB[1];
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);

}

static void performance2() {
    int a=0; 
    int b=0;
    int[] arrayA = { 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] arrayB = { 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4 };
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            b = arrayB[arrayA[2]];
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);

}
```

The first method takes 209 ms to execute on my system, the seccond 4295! so 20 times as much. How can this be? As far as i can see this i can get a 20time performance increase if i declare 3 seperate variables instead of arrayA, because the following method executes very fast again:

```
static void performance3() {
    int a=0; 
    int b=0;
    int[] arrayA = { 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] arrayB = { 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4 };
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            b = arrayB[a];
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);

}
```

Am i overlooking something obvious here? it really seems suprising to me that the difference is so huge. Thank you anyways for explanations:)

Comment: In the first method you're always accessing the same elements so the compiler will most likely optimize that. In the second method the compiler can't optimize the access to `arrayB` as it doesn't know the index at compile time (since it could change at runtime).

Comment: You do realize that `arrayB[a]` is always `arrayB[0]`?

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine and all methods take similarly long so it's probably something else. What JDK are you using? How do you call them?

Comment: yes i do realize, it was just for testing purposes, the thing is, if i declare 3 different variables instead of arrayA, i get a huge perfomance gain, which seems odd to me

Comment: thats strange, i use jdk 8u60

Comment: @Nellieder well it might be my eclipse compiler which probably doesn't do such optimizations. Need to test it with another compiler.

Comment: Just tested it again with the Oracle compiler and I get similar results to yours. This indicates that the Oracle compiler will optimize methods 1 and 3 while the Eclipse compiler won't do any optimizations. Thus: without optimization performance is the same, with optimization you get way better performance in those direct access cases (as already explained in several comments and answers).

Comment: yes thats it, thank you very much. What a coincidenece that my loop had just the right size to make the result at least somehow comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, a is always set to 5 and b to 5, regardless of what your loop indices are, so the compiler has eliminated the loops entirely, so it really ends up something like:

```
int a=0; 
int b=0;
int[] arrayA = { 3, 4, 5 };
int[] arrayB = { 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4 };
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
a = 5;
b = 5;
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

Comment: thats it thank you:) didnt get it first, because you get some time increase if you make the loop big enough, but now if i add a zero it takes the same time.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `b = arrayB[1];` it directly references the value stored at location `1` but when you do `b = arrayB[arrayA[2]];` it has to first retrieve the value `arrayA[2]` and then retrieve the value of `arrayB[]` based on the value retrieve in the earlier step.

The compiler is smart enough to optimize the activity in first step but not in the second step.

It will be more clear if you look the the byte code generated by these two methods.

Comment: ok, i understand that it should be slower, but i expected something like maybe factor 2 and definitly not factor 20-40

Comment: @Nellieder Why do you think so?

Comment: Another reason for performance increase: in the bottom code, there can be side effects at runtime like exceptions, while in the top code these side effects can be evaluated before the loop even starts

Comment: i am a highlevel guy, so i am not sure, but from my understanding b = arrayB[arrayA[2]] are two lookups and b = arrayB[1] is one lookup, so i think it should take about twice as long